# Size of data members in class doesn't match

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have this class:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        shared_ptr<X> a;
        shared_ptr<Y> b;
        std::string c;
        std::vector<double> d;
        std::vector<shared_ptr<Z>> e;
        int f;
};
```

and when I compile on VS2012 with the switch to see the class layout I get this:

```
1>  class MyClass   size(128):
1>      +---
1>   0  | {vfptr}
1>   8  | ?$shared_ptr@VX@@ a
1>  24  | ?$shared_ptr@VY@@ b
1>  40  | ?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@ c
1>  72  | ?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@ d
1>  96  | ?$vector@V?$shared_ptr@Z@@@boost@@V?$allocator@V?$shared_ptr@VZ@@@boost@@@std@@ e
1>  120 | f
1>      | <alignment member> (size=4)
1>      +---
```

It implies data member `c` is 32 bytes.

However, if I do `sizeof(std::string)` on my platform (Win 7 64), with MSVC11 I get 40 bytes.

Why does `sizeof()` give me 40 but the above compiler memory layout imply 32?

Comment: Why does it show a vtable pointer when the class with no virtual functions?

Comment: @MobyDisk I removed the methods to concentrate on the data members.

Comment: @user997112: Don't remove things that you assume are unimportant. Show us the *exact* code you compiled, and the *exact* output you get for that code.

Comment: And the exact compilation options.  In the Visual C++ implementation, the sizes of Standard Library types may vary depending on compilation options.

Comment: Does this class layout show any padding that might be there?

Comment: The layout does not match the source presented - a vtable is present which should not be there

Answer (score -1):

data member c is probably a pointer to the string object. Since std::string stores a string of variable size, there is no way you can fit anything you want in that space.

So it is a pointer, managed by the language and not by you.

Comment: .. and a pointer is 40 bytes?    It's some padding issue (==member alignment, pragma pack's and such).   Hope the OP would clarify the exact setting.